# Preloading images in a Modal-component

Tags: react-native

I have a component which consists of a FlatList and a Modal-component. This modal component has several Image-components. The images are set by the *source*-attribute to an external url.

I switch die visibility of the modal-component by changing the *visible* attribute.

The problem:
Everytime I open the modal (at the beginning or after closing it) the images are loaded from the server. So there are no images for maybe 1 second.
Are the images deleted from the cache if I set the visible of the modal to false??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching of images can be related to multiple things. The most effective one is probably the [`Cache-Control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) header sent from the server when you request the image. You can check the headers to see if the request has a low time on cache.

The other thing is that, while development process, building or hot-reloading of the app can result in clearing the cache for the app.

Another reason can be the low storage in device might be triggering the OS to delete cached images.

In iOS you can control caching. More info can be find [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#cache-control-ios-only).

Its hard to tell without any sample code but, if you are mounting and then unmounting Modal when you set the visibility of it, you can try to prefetch images before mounting the Modal. If the caching control is right when you mount the Modal they should be served from the cache. If the images you are trying to show are large it might be a performance issue or they might be taking long time to load from the disk. You can debug this with a less number of item in modal with smaller images.

Hope the information above is going to be enough.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [react-native-img-cache](https://github.com/wcandillon/react-native-img-cache) 
or [react-native-cached-image](https://github.com/kfiroo/react-native-cached-image) to cash your images

and yes the images in react native are not cached by default

also to preload images you can use [react-native-fast-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image)